# Finding common elements without duplicates in two lists using OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Im trying to implement a rec function in OCaml, but I dont know how to filter out the duplicated common element in the result list, here is my implementation:

```
let rec common twolists =
    match twolists with
    | (x, y) ->
         match x with
         | [] -> []
         | s :: ss ->
             if memberof (s, y) then
                 s :: common (ss, y)
             else 
                 common (ss, y)
;;
```

I found all the common element in the 2 lists, but i dont know how to do it without any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to replace this expression:

```
s :: common (ss, y)
```

with something a little more complicated.

If `s` is already a member of `common (ss, y)` you don't want to add it again. So you can replace this expression with two cases depending on whether `s` is already there.

For this you would probably want to use `let`:

```
let rest = common (ss, y) in
. . .
```

(Note that if this were production code where the lists can get long, you would want to avoid repeatedly calling `memberof`. You might end up using trees. I.e., sets. Then the result is a completely straightforward set intersection.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's simplify your code by realizing we can directly pattern match on `x` in the top-level match expression.

```
let rec common twolists =
  match twolists with
  | ([], _) -> []
  | (s::ss, y) ->
    if memberof (s, y) then
      s :: common (ss, y)
    else 
      common (ss, y)
```

Now, let's use an accumulator and not pass the two lists as a tuple because it's not very idiomatic for OCaml. Bonus: this is now tail-recursive.

```
let rec common lst1 lst2 acc =
  match lst1, lst2 with
  | ([], _) -> List.rev acc
  | (s::ss, y) ->
    if memberof (s, y) then
      common ss y (s :: acc)
    else 
      common ss y acc
```

We might want to hide this accumulator by making it a locally bound function.

```
let common lst1 lst2 =
  let rec common' lst1 lst2 acc =
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | ([], _) -> List.rev acc
    | (s::ss, y) ->
      if memberof (s, y) then
        common' ss y (s :: acc)
      else 
        common' ss y acc
  in
  common' lst1 lst2 []
```

But the trick is doing the lookup in `memberof` over and over again. If we don't need to preserve order, this is a lot easier if both lists are *sorted*.

```
let common lst1 lst2 =
  let rec common' lst1 lst2 acc =
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | ([], _) -> List.rev acc
    | (s::ss, y) ->
      if memberof (s, y) then
        common' ss y (s :: acc)
      else 
        common' ss y acc
  in
  List.(
    common' (sort compare lst1) (sort compare lst2) []
  )
```

Now if we call something like:

```
common [1; 4; 4; 3; 6; 2] [5; 7; 2; 6; 4; 4]
```

We're really calling:

```
common' [1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 6] [2; 4; 4; 5; 6; 7]
```

By knowing that we're sorted, things become simpler. Let's match on `lst1`, `lst2`, and `acc`. Because `acc` is built up "backwards" we can easily pattern match on the last element added to it to check for duplicates.

```
let common lst1 lst2 = 
  let rec common' lst1 lst2 acc =
    match lst1, lst2, acc with
    | [], _, _  
    | _, [], _ -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs, y::ys, z::_ when x = y && x = z -> common' xs ys acc
    | x::xs, y::ys, _ when x = y -> common' xs ys (x :: acc)
    | x::xs, y::_, _ when x < y -> common' xs lst2 acc
    | _, _::ys, _ -> common' lst1 ys acc
  in
  common' 
    (List.sort compare lst1) 
    (List.sort compare lst2)
    []
```

Testing:

```
# common [1; 5; 2; 3; 3; 9; 0] [0; 3; 1; 7; 3; 8];;
- : int list = [0; 1; 3]
```

If we break this down:

```
common [1; 5; 2; 3; 3; 9; 0] [0; 3; 1; 7; 3; 8]
common' [0; 1; 2; 3; 3; 5; 9] [0; 1; 3; 3; 7; 8] []
common' [1; 2; 3; 3; 5; 9] [1; 3; 3; 7; 8] [0]
common' [2; 3; 3; 5; 9] [3; 3; 7; 8] [1; 0]
common' [3; 3; 5; 9] [3; 3; 7; 8] [1; 0]
common' [3; 5; 9] [3; 7; 8] [3; 1; 0]
common' [5; 9] [7; 8] [3; 1; 0]
common' [9] [7; 8] [3; 1; 0]
common' [9] [8] [3; 1; 0]
common' [9] [] [3; 1; 0]
List.rev [3; 1; 0]
[0; 1; 3]
```

Of course, we can ultimately realize that this is a set intersection and utilize the [`Set`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Set.html) module.

```
# let common lst1 lst2 =
    let open Set.Make (Int) in
    let set1 = of_list lst1 in
    let set2 = of_list lst2 in
    set1 |> inter set2 |> to_list;;
val common : int list -> int list -> int list = <fun>
# common [1; 5; 2; 3; 3; 9; 0] [0; 3; 1; 7; 3; 8];;
- : int list = [0; 1; 3]
```